# Formatting only selected elements in a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series, number-formatting

This is a hopefully quick question.  How can I format only some of the elements in a Pandas series?  Here is the code and output.

```
a=pd.Series({'a':1.2345, 'b':2.3456,'c':3.4567})

a
Out[49]: 
a    1.2345
b    2.3456
c    3.4567
dtype: float64

a.loc[['a','b']].round(decimals=1)
Out[50]: 
a    1.2
b    2.3
dtype: float64

a.loc[['a','b']]=a.loc[['a','b']].round(decimals=1)

a
Out[53]: 
a    1.2000
b    2.3000
c    3.4567
dtype: float64
```

So it seems like the round only truncates in the display, but still keeps 4 decimal places in the output.  What I would like to see is:

```
Out[53]: 
a    1.2
b    2.3
c    3.4567
dtype: float64
```

This is in context to outputting the Series to a csv file.

Is there any Pandas(y) way other than brute force doing it one element at a time (such as list comprehension)?

thanks,

Comment: You have not provided the logic for determining which values to round.

Comment: Pandas applies the precision to the entire column, since you are only rounding some values, the precision of the column is not changed. If you round the entire column, then you will see the resulting Series, only has 1 decimal place.

Comment: The only way you could achieve this would be to use strings (i.e. if you want to export to csv)

Comment: Thanks all.  I was afraid that the only way is to brute force do a string format for each element specifically, but hoped there was a clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to display floats in some specific format, then we can apply:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:g}'.format
```

The value for `float_format` should be callable. Here I apply format to be general. The output on the screen will look like this:

```
a      1.2
b      2.3
c   3.4567
d        1
e    1e-06
dtype: float64
```

To make it work only on a specific frame, we can use `Styler`:

```
a.to_frame().style.format('{:g}')
```

Note, that in this case we can apply format to a specific subset of labels, see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format) for details.

As for the csv-files, `to_csv` method has the `float_format` option. Here's how it works:

```
from io import StringIO
buf = StringIO()

a.to_csv(buf,  float_format='%g')

print(buf.getvalue())
```

We obtain the following csv-content:

```
,0
a,1.2
b,2.3
c,3.4567
d,1
e,1e-06
```

---

P.S.
See also [Details about formatting language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)